# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework User Impersonation Failing

Tags: asp.net-core, impersonation

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core webapp that requires forwarding the user's window's credentials to use for database access through Entity Framework. But an exception is thrown on database access. `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.'`.

I have tried using impersonation in middleware, as well as around the query itself. The way I invoke it is:

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = ((WindowsIdentity)User.Identity).Impersonate())
{
    var debug2 = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // shows the desired user
    entiryFrameworkContext.BlahBlahBlah.ToList();
}
```

Or if I'm taking the middleware approach:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = ((WindowsIdentity)context.User.Identity).Impersonate())
        {
            var debug = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); // shows the desired user
            await next.Invoke();
        }
    });
```

The results are the same whether in release mode pushed to IIS or running in VS2017 IIS Express.

Does anyone have an idea why the anonymous user is still used for db calls? And if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: I'm willing to provide all the additional detail on this that I can, I just don't know what would be useful here. I'm in brand new territory here.

Comment: I'd make sure to disable Anonymous Authentication.